# Polymer: wrap parent element around child

Tags: polymer, web-component

with Polymer it's easy to extend another web component. You can use `<shadow>` to mark the place in the child's template where the shadow dom of the Parent should be ([polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#extending-other-elements)).

I'm looking to extend an element, but in a way that a specific part of child gets wrapped by the parent. This kind of setup I've used with some template engines. Can this be done with html includes?

Parent ::

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="tpl-parent" noscript>
  <template>
    <section>
      <content></content><!-- put the child template here -->
    </section>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Child ::

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="parent.html">

<polymer-element name="tpl-child" extends="tpl-parent" noscript>
  <template>
    <shadow>
      <p>whatever I put here should be "wrapped" by the _section_ in parent</p>
    </shadow>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though @robdodson's answer is completely correct, it kind of feels.. too "loose".

When discussing this further at work, somebody noted the principle of "[Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)". This led to me viewing this situation from a different (and I think better) perspective.

I ended up with this (also includes an example of passing arguments):

-- x-foo.html

```
<polymer-element name="x-foo" arguments="status">
  <template>
    <style>
      #wrapper.valid ::content p { color: green; }
      #wrapper.invalid ::content p { color: red; }
    </style>
    <section id="wrapper">
      <p>x-bar will be put in the content tag below</p>
      <content></content>
    </section>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      status: '',
      statusChanged: function(oldVal, newVal) {
        if (['valid', 'invalid'].indexOf(newVAl) === -1) {
          this.$.wrapper.setAttribute('class', newVal);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

-- x-bar.html

```
<link rel="import" href="x-foo.html" arguments="status">

<polymer-element name="x-bar">
  <template>
    <x-foo status="{{status}}">
      <p>color me</p>
    </x-foo>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

-- index.html

```
<link rel="import" href="x-bar.html" arguments="status">
<x-bar></x-bar>
```

The only "disadvantage" is you have to pass on "status". But this feels better then having to append to a "floating" div#wrapper in the super class

Comment: Nice, solved the same issue like you suggested. Works great for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it declaratively like that. But I think you can leverage automatic node finding to move a child into the parent's section if it has an id.

```
<polymer-element name="x-foo">
  <template>
    <style>
      #wrapper p { color: red; }
    </style>
    <section id="wrapper">
      <p>Hello from x-foo</p>
    </section>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="x-bar" extends="x-foo">
  <template>
    <p id="foo">I was wrapped by x-foo</p>
    <p>I was not wrapped</p>
    <shadow></shadow>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      domReady: function() {
        this.$.wrapper.appendChild(this.$.foo);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<x-bar></x-bar>
```